# ASP.NET: How to retrieve the name of the logged-in user?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Afternoon All,

I have a web site where i need to know who is inserting a record into my database table.  I have a group of users which i have populated into an Active Directory (AD) group and in turn they are the only members able to access the site. (See web.config code and .vb code below)

'Config File

```
     <appSettings>
           <add key="dbConnection" value="Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;"/>
           <add key="Users" value="Users_General_Access"/>
     </appSettings>
```

'Vb Code

```
    If User.IsInRole(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Users")) Then

    Else
        Response.Redirect("NotAuthorised.aspx")
    End If
```

I have a stored procedure that is used to insert data from my form fields into the database which work fine.

The problem that i have is that im not asking the user to log in as they are able to do so via the AD set up. However i need to caputre the username so i can populate this into my database table to state who has added that record.

Is there some VB code that i can use to obtain this information?

Many thanks in advance 
Betty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

OR only  `User.Identity.Name` as according to OP's code `User` is in the scope

will  give you user name. use can access other information using

`User.Identity`

Comment: You don't need to specify HttpContext.Current.User, as User is already in scope. You only need to write User.Identity.Name

Comment: @RabNawaz - Many Thanks, i will  be able to use this just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the Current User Name using your Application by:

```
string loggedUser = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
```

Once you have this, you can store in Database

Pass the loggedUser to the database

Answer (score 0):

As other have said, you can get the name of the logged-in user with `User.Identity.Name`.

You can also get rid of the code that checks for role membership if you add the proper tags in web.config. Checking membership in code is useful only if the name of the role is not known in advance and can't be stored in the web.config file, eg. when the roles come from a database.

You can [specify the roles](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2008/09/29/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config.aspx) authorized to visit a specific page using the [location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx) tag:

```
<configuration>
 ....
 <location path="MySecurePage.aspx">    
      <system.web>    
           <authorization>    
                <allow roles="Administrators,MyGroup" />    
                <deny users="*"/>
           </authorization>    
      </system.web>    
 </location> 
</configuration>
```